# Converting infix to binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, infix-notation

How can you convert an infix expression into a tree? I would like to do it manually rather than programming first. For example, let's look at this infix expression:

```
b = (x * a) - y / b * (c + d)
```

What are the rules to turning this into a tree? Or what steps do you suggest to take to do this? I'm having trouble here because sometimes these expressions don't have explicit parentheses in them:

```
b = x * a - y / b * c + d
```

Comment: Operators/functions may take 0 to n arguments, so normally  an expression does not have to be a binary tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you're describing here is generally called *expression parsing* and typically there are two steps in the process:

First, there's *scanning*, where you take your input string and break it apart into a bunch of smaller logical units, each of which represents a single "piece" of the input. For example, given the input string

```
b = x * a - y / b * c + d
```

You might produce this sequence of tokens:

```
[b] [=] [x] [*] [a] [-] [y] [/] [b] [*] [c] [+] [d]
```

This way, you move from "the input is a sequence of characters" to "the input is a sequence of individual variables, operators, etc." There are many ways to do this step, and they often involve doing some manually string processing or working with regular expressions (if you're familiar with those). As a first step, see if you can get this part working.

The second step, which is probably the one you're most hung up on, is *parsing*, where you take that sequence of tokens and reconstruct the meaning of the statement. This usually involves figuring out the operator precedence and actually building up the tree structure you want. That tree, by the way, is often called an *expression tree* or an *[abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)* (AST).

There are many ways to do this. For parsing expressions, my personal go-to is [Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). This algorithm works by maintaining two stacks and processing the tokens one at a time, using the stacks to determine what the operators should be applied to.

If you'd like to see an example of how to do this, I built a [truth table generator](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1176/tools/truth-table-tool/) for a discrete math class that I regularly teach. You type in a logical expression, and the code scans it to get a token sequence, then uses the shunting-yard algorithm to build up an AST, which is then used to generate the truth table tool. The [source code](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1176/tools/truth-table-tool/js/) is broken down so that each step is done separately, and that might make for a good reference.